# Group suppressing based on page numbers

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a warranty statement that needs to be print only in the second page of the report.
I tried using Selection Expert, Suppress (No Drill-Down). I add PageNumber<>2 formula in it. However, when I run my report it keeps the entire section suppressed for all pages.

I am new to crystal report!.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to print that statement only in the last page, you can place that in the report footer of a report. And FYI, Report Footer will be the last section in a report which is always printed on the last page of report.

If that's not the case then I need more information such as 
1. How many pages does this report has ? 
2. Will it contain more than 2 pages all the time ?
3. And I wanted to know the section in which you had placed the warranty statement ?

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Well the length of the report is unknown and based upon the data volume that user have in his database. So as a result of that report may have 1, 2 or more than 2 pages depending on the amount of data been viewed. I tried placing the warranty statement in lot of places. So far I have only manage to display it as the last page of the report. In simple terms what I want is to without considering the number of pages in the report show the warranty statement as the second page of report.
I hope I made my self clear!